# How to use dotnet highcharts dll to show HighCharts in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying a method to bind data to the Pie chart

```
  Public ActionResult Charts
  {
      Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
        .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
        .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010" })
        .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
        {
            Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
            {
                AllowPointSelect = true,
                Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                {
                    Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                    ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                    Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                }
            }
        })
        .SetSeries(new Series
        {
            Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
            Name = "Browser share",
            Data = new Data(new object[]
                                   {
                                       new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                                       new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                                       new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
                                       {
                                           Name = "Chrome",
                                           Y = 12.8,
                                           Sliced = true,
                                           Selected = true
                                       },
                                       new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                                       new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                                       new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                                   })
                             });
        }
    }

    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        int Param1;
        Param1 = 1;     
        var reports = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ResourceReports>("ResourceReports @EmployeeID", new SqlParameter("@EmployeeID", Param1)).ToList();
        return Json(reports, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

i want to replace

```
    .SetSeries(new Series
    {
        Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
        Name = "Browser share",
        Data = new Data(new object[]
                                   {
                                       new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                                       new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                                       new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
                                       {
                                           Name = "Chrome",
                                           Y = 12.8,
                                           Sliced = true,
                                           Selected = true
                                       },
                                       new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                                       new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                                       new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                                   })
        });
    }
```

with my `GetData()` how can i do this,the Data in `.SetSeries` should be my returned data in `GetData method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using Dotnet.Highcharts. You could create a list of `Series` and a list of `Point`.

```
List<Series> mySeries = new List<Series>();
List<Point> myPoints = new List<Point>();
```

I would loop through each series you need to create and generate the point data like so:

```
myPoints.Add(new Point {
    X = (detailRec.RecordTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalMilliseconds,
    Y = detailRec.TotalCount
});
```

Then you could create the series itself using the list of points for its data like so:

```
mySeries.Add(new Series{
  Name = distinctDistrict.Name,
  Data = new Data(myPoints.ToArray())
});
```

Then to set the Series you could use the following statement:

```
.SetSeries(mySeries.Select(s => new Series { 
  Name = s.Name, 
  Data = s.Data 
}).ToArray())
```

If you use the object browser in Visual Studio, you can see the other properties and methods of the `Series` and `Point` class.  To use the above code you will have to include the the following using statements:

```
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using Point = DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point;
```

Comment: @Tommmy Johnson.....my question was .SetSeries should be my returned data in GetData method

Comment: You can not return a `SetSeries` as that is a method to set the series.  However you can return a `Series` object.  In the example above you would return `mySeries`.  Then use that in the `SetSeries` method to add your series to the chart.